# Why can't I define a object of class(which inherited another class) outside the main function?

Tags: c++, fltk

I am currently working with VS15 using the fltk library. When I try to create an object of my class (which inherits Fl_Double_Window) outside the main function the program crashed.

```
#include"FL/Fl.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Double_Window.h"
#include"FL/Fl_draw.h"
#include"FL/Fl_Slider.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Input.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Button.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Text_Display.H"
#include<string>

struct MyWindow :Fl_Double_Window {
    MyWindow(string s):Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, s.c_str()){
        color(FL_BLACK);
        show();
    }
};

MyWindow window("Special");

int main()
{
    return Fl::run();
}
```

However, everything works properly when I create an object of class Fl_Double_Window directly (again outside the main function):

```
#include"FL/Fl.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Double_Window.h"
#include"FL/Fl_draw.h"
#include"FL/Fl_Slider.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Input.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Button.H"
#include"FL/Fl_Text_Display.H"
#include<string>

string name = "Special";
Fl_Double_Window window(10, 10, 500, 500, name.c_str());

int main()
{
    window.color(FL_BLACK);
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

The guy I downloaded the code from run the code on Ubuntu using C++11, and the program works in both cases.
I’m confused and I really can’t figure out what the problem is.

Comment: A char ptr to a temporary, sounds like UB (undefined behavior)

Comment: in case you do not understand @JVApen speak about  `s.c_str()` in `MyWindow(string s):Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, s.c_str()){...}` because by definition *s* is temporary so so you cannot suppose something about the duration of its internal pointer returned by `c_str()`

Comment: Why are you using `char*`rather than `string` in *Fl_Double_Window* ?

Comment: @bruno i don't know, that's just what the creators of the FLTK library decided.

Comment: @Xeron if you cannot use literal string in place of `std::string` to name your windows duplicate the result of `c_str()` e.g. `strdup(xxx.c_str())` ... even the lib get the pointer as `const` so will never free it, it is a pity to have a C++ lib using `char *` ...

Comment: @bruno i tried that too but the program kept crashing.

Comment: @Xeron doing what ? `MyWindow(const char * s):Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, s){...}` ? or `MyWindow(string s):Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, strdup(s.c_str())){...}` ? Note while you name your windows with a literal string (e.g.  `"Special"`) the first solution is the best

Comment: @bruno I tried `MyWindow(const char * s):Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, s){...}` , but the program stopped working

Comment: BTW perhaps you cannot do `show();` inside the constructor, in your second proposal you call show and color outside of it

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a crash because you've put show (as mentioned by @bruno) in the constructor.  If you take show out of the constructor and put it in main, you won't get the crash that you are seeing but the title will be incorrect for the reasons that @Sam Varshavchik has mentioned.

```
struct MyWindow :Fl_Double_Window {
    MyWindow(const std::string& s)
   :    Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500) // 1) Do not set the title here
    ,   caption(s)  // 2) Take a copy of the title
    {
        // 3) Set the title here
        this->copy_label(caption.c_str());
        color(FL_BLACK);
        // 4) Remove show from constructor
        // show();
    }

    // 5) Declare caption - see Sam's solution
    std::string caption;
};

MyWindow window("Special");


int main()
{
    // 6) Move show here
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: I said that the Jun 27 in a remark to the OP question but no reaction from OP.

Comment: I only just saw that - didn't expand on the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyWindow(string s)
```

A constructor is not much different from a function. `s` is a parameter to the constructor. Once the constructor returns, `s` gets destroyed.

```
                  :Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, s.c_str()){
```

`c_str()` returns a pointer to `s`'s contents, and passes it to the superclass's constructor. However because `s` will get destroyed, any further usage of that pointer becomes undefined behavior, and a likely crash. Which is what's obviously happening.

The solution is slightly complicated. This requires a delicate juggling act if you still wish to inherit from `FL_Double_Window`:

```
struct my_data {
    string s_name;
    my_data(string s) : s_name(s)
    {
    }
};

struct MyWindow :my_data, Fl_Double_Window {

    MyWindow(string s): my_data(s),
                        Fl_Double_Window(10, 10, 500, 500, this->s_name.c_str()){
        color(FL_BLACK);
        show();
    }
};
```

This juggles the order in which things get constructed and destroyed so that the `s_name` class member continues to exist as long as FL_DoubleWindow exists.

There's also the (much) easier option of passing in a reference, but then you will have to ensure that the referenced `std::string` exists as long as the window object exists. This approach, although slightly cumbersome, is also more bulletproof.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the program continued to crash...

Comment: And what does your debugger show to be the reason for the crash?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x777029CC (ole32.dll) in First_example.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Comment: Your debugger shows much more information than that. For example, the debugger shows the values of all variables, in each stack frame, and lets you determine the exact reason for the crash. When I compile and link my version (after adding the missing `using namespace std` that you must have), the program runs without issues, and opens a black window. Your crash must be because of some other code, not this one. You should spend some time learning how to use a debugger. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Yes, I'm just learning C++ from the book Principles and Practices Using C++ by Stroustrup, so I haven't gotten to the debugger yet. Are you sure you define a MyWindow object outside the main function, because even the program works for me when I define a MyWindow object inside the main function?

Comment: There's no need to to ask me. You can trivially answer this yourself, simply by copy/pasting ***only the shown code*** (and adding the missing `using namespace std;`), compiling it, running it, and seeing it for yourself. Now, although I am not familiar with that book, I doubt that there's anything in there related to FLTK. It's hard enough to learn core C++, the most complicated genreal purpose programming language to use today; but also trying to learn FLTK at the same time just makes things tens times more difficult. Focus on that book, learn and understand core C++ first.